# Lost my phone with the wallet in it... Any way to recuperate my 5.178 bitcoins?

Tags: security

Phone and car got stolen, i had the keychain of my wallet on a pad, so it's all gone, everything!! Please tell me there's a way to get them back?

Comment: What kind of wallet was it? Do you still have a seed? Or a backup of the wallet on your computer or on your cloud storage?

Comment: don't you think it is a little bit careless to have the private key for >5btc on a phone without a backup? only a very little bit careless?!

Answer (score 1):

To spend bitcoins, you need the private keys that control your address(es). There is no other way to spend your coins, without the keys your coins will likely sit unspent forever. So that means you'll need:

a) your phone

b) a backup copy of the private keys, or (more likely) the wallet's mnemonic seed phrase

c) a digital backup of your phone

It sounds like a) and b) are not viable options for you, but perhaps you can recover some of your phone's data from a local backup/cloud storage. Normally I would recommend *not* storing wallet backup data in the cloud, but in this case it may be your only hope of recovery.

Sorry for your loss, best of luck.